# Remote language server can't activate when I open ASP.Net MVC solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Recently, my ASP.Net project have been giving me issues, as soon as I open the project it displays the error:

> There was an error activating the remote language server, C#/Visual Basic Server Client. For more details, please examine the ActivityLog.xml file.

I examined the *ActivityLog.xml* file as it suggested, and from the Activity Monitor Log I found the following errors:

1. > **#182:** Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.Client, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   > c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\commonextensions\platform\diagnosticshub\Microsoft.DiagnosticsHub.VisualStudio.Package.dll
2. > **#183:** Still unable to load MEF component DLL: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.UniversalApps.Deployment, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   > C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO\2019\COMMUNITY\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\MICROSOFT\GRAPHICS\DEBUGGER\VsGraphicsDebuggerPkg.dll

I tried to repair VS2019 with hopes it will fix this error, but it didn't work. And I'm using the latest version of VS2019 (version 16.8.3).

Comment: Have you managed to resolve this? I am having the same issue.

Comment: @su8898 no, I didn't. I think it's a bug with VS2019 because when I run the same project on VS2017 it works perfectly. For now, I'm coding on VS2017 until I find a solution or the bug gets fixed.

Comment: I ended up reinstalling VS2019 and it resolved the issue!